# Check for the orientation in the IDE layout editor

Tags: android, orientation, android-studio, custom-view

I'm writing a custom layout that is depending its lay-outing on the orientation of the device. For this I use the following call:

```
if (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
  .....
}
```

When running this on a device, this works fine and I see my custom layout responding to the orientation changes.

I would also have the same working in my layout editor of my IDE (Eclipse or Android Studio). So that I can see both landscape and portrait correctly in my editor. 
When I try this somehow getResources().getConfiguration().orientation always has the value of 0 which is according to the documentation **Configuration.ORIENTATION_UNDEFINED**.

Is there maybe some other way to retrieve the orientation in general or just for the editor? Or is this just not supported by the Android developer tools?

Comment: I'm confused, in the layout editor in Android Studio you can hit a button to switch from landscape/portrait. But it sounds like you're creating your layout programmatically? Any reason you're not using a landscape oriented layout xml instead?

Comment: No, I'm not doing the layout programmatically. I have a layout in xml, that includes a custom layout. That custom layout is what I'm talking about in my question. In that custom layout I want to retrieve the orientation programmatically. But it doesn't seem to work when I hit the button to switch the orientation in the layout editor.

Comment: I guess I don't understand what you mean at all then. What does it mean to retrieve the orientation from within the layout xml?

Comment: I have a view within my layout and I want to know the orientation of the device. And I want to know that in the android layout editor.

Comment: I'm still confused. Don't you select the orientation in the layout editor?

Comment: I don't know how to make it more clear for you. At the end it doesn't matter. Tor Norbye already identified the problem in the Android SDK and filed a bug for it.

Comment: I apparently can't read, I get it now - glad to see it is getting resolved!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't possible; we use the device orientation to pick the best matching layout resource to render in the layout editor (similar to what happens at runtime), but we don't also push an orientation value into getResources().getConfiguration().orientation layoutlib, our rendering library which runs portions of view code. We probably should. Would you mind filing a bug for this at http://b.android.com with category Component-Tools?

Comment: Bug is already there => https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=57377 ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Found this similar link

[Getting orientation of Android device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14955728/getting-orientation-of-android-device)

...hope it serves your purpose .

Comment: This isn't really an answer. It should have been posted as a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Tor Norbye (Android Tools) has responded that this is not possible at this moment and filled a [bug](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=57377) to solve this.
You can read his answer on [Google+](https://plus.google.com/117635401023505776450/posts/HzbhFruEBfb).